# Numpy `Broadcast` array

Tags: numpy, matrix

I would like to do a transformation like `dimshuffle` in theano using numpy.

Example input:

```
np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
```

Example output:

```
np.array([
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `dimshuffle` does, but the output can be produced with `repeat`

```
In [319]: np.repeat(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])[None,:,:],3,axis=0)
Out[319]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```

The input is 2d `(2,3)`, so I have to add an axis - output is `(3,2,3)`.  `tile` would work, so would indexing, or even:

```
A=np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
np.array([A,A,A])
```